# Python - Request being blocked by Cloudflare

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to log into a website. When I look at print(g.text) I am not getting back the web page I expect but instead a cloudflare page that says 'Checking your browser before accessing'

```
import requests
import time

s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/')

headers = {'Referer': 'https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/login'}

payload = {
    'utf8':'✓',
    'authenticity_token':'',
    'spree_user[email]': 'EMAIL@gmail.com',
    'spree_user[password]': 'PASSWORD',
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
    'commit': 'Login'
}

r = s.post('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/login', data=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)

g = s.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/account')

print(g.status_code)
print(g.text)
```

Why is this occurring when I have set the session?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the page uses Cloudflare's anti-bot page (or IUAM). 
Bypassing this check is quite difficult to solve on your own, since Cloudflare changes their techniques periodically. Currently, they check if the client supports JavaScript, which can be spoofed.
I would recommend using the `cfscrape` module for bypassing this. 
To install it, use `pip install cfscrape`. You'll also need to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).
You can pass a requests session into `create_scraper()` like so:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = ...
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)
```

Comment: @Pthomas did you implement? Do you want to share your experiments?

Comment: @jeremiah i am trying it now. and it is  raising some exception [here](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/issues/232)

Answer (score 45):

You might want to try this:

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()  # returns a CloudScraper instance
# Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
print scraper.get("http://somesite.com").text  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

It does not require Node.js dependency.
All credits go to [this pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)

Comment: It seems that cloudscraper is not totally free. In my case cloudscraper showed error message, something like "cloudflare v2 detected. Not available in free version". So i think, one need to pay to access all cloudscraper features.

Comment: It works just fine, I just checked it, make sure that the following packages are up to date:
`Requests >= 2.9.2`
`Requests_toolbelt >= 0.9.1`
as described here https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/ under the dependencies heading.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because they implemented cloudfare in the api, I solved it this way

```
import cloudscraper
import json
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
r = scraper.get("MY API").text 
y = json.loads(r)
print (y)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can scrape any Cloudflare protected page by using this tool. Node.js is mandatory in order for the code to work correctly.

Download Node from this link https://nodejs.org/en/

```
import cfscrape #pip install cfscrape

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
res = scraper.get("https://www.example.com").text
print(res)
```

Comment: How can I integrate this with scrapy?

Comment: That's a great tool! I works perfectly to get the page behind CloudFlare security.

Comment: Didn't work for me as of 3/4/2024: <title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>

Comment: The post is two years old. A lot of new features would have been added by CF in the mean time. However, you can use the undetected-chromedriver package to scrape CF protected sites.

Answer (score 4):

`curl` and `hx` avoid this problem. But how?
I found, they work by default with HTTP/2. But `requests` library used only HTTP/1.1.

So, for tests I installed `httpx` with `h2` python library to support HTTP/2 requests) and it works if I do: `httpx --http2 'https://some.url'`.

So, the solution is to use a library that supports http2. For example `httpx` with `h2`

It's not a complete solution, since it won't help to solve Cloudflare's anti-bot ("I'm Under Attack Mode", or IUAM) challenge

Comment: Actually, `httpx` can succeed even with just 1.1, without a need for 2. I suspect this could be due to a difference in ciphers used by `requests` and `httpx`.