# External API access with Ruby blocked by CloudFlare

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudflare

I am trying to access the HaveIBeenPwned web API for breached sites and emails, but I am being blocked by cloudflare's anti-DDoS protection. I've found that there are ways to get around this with Python and JavaScript, but I haven't been successful with my React/Rails app.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087990/python-request-being-blocked-by-cloudflare/) has the following quote: "Currently, they check if the client supports JavaScript, which can be spoofed." I haven't been able to find any other documentation of this behavior.

I need this information in the backend, so calling HIBP from the frontend is not ideal. Any idea how to hit the API from Rails?

Answer (score 0):

If they want it to be used on frontend only, using it on backend can be tricky. You will need to create your own wrapper with, for example, [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). And from Rails side execute command that will do some work in background. But keep in mind, it doesn't work very fast (can take up to 5 seconds per request), and it will block your Rails process.

I would start with single node.js app that will accept command-line parameters. Ruby isn't very good at advanced web scraping, so there are no any gentle solutions. Also, keep in mind that you don't have any guarantees. One day it can just stop working.