# Scraping news headlines using requests or selenium can't return data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape news headlines from this page: https://www.forexfactory.com/news
while scrolling down and clicking on more button.
[image]

I tried requests and bs4 but didn't return data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

u = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u, timeout=30, headers=headers)     # print(r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

soup.select('.flexposts__item.flexposts__story') # return []

print(r.status_code) #return 503
```

I checked Network button on the console and find other urls which return raw response data:
[image]

I tried using requests but same response: 503

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

u = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?more=2'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u, timeout=30, headers=headers)     

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print(r.status_code) #return 503

print(r.text) #return html but without the headlines content

soup.select('.flexposts__item.flexposts__story') # return []
```

I also tried selenium but same, don't return headlines elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")          

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
u = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'
driver.get(u)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.flexposts__item.flexposts__story') # return []

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
soup.select('.flexposts__item.flexposts__story') # return []

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are being blocked by [Cloudflare DDoS protection](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172676-Understanding-Cloudflare-DDoS-protection):

> A Distributed Denial of Service attack (DDoS) seeks to make an online
> service unavailable to its end users.  For all plan types, Cloudflare
> provides unmetered mitigation of DDoS attacks at Layer 3, 4, and 7.

If you print the output for `soup.prettify()` you will see:

```
...
 <div class="attribution">
       DDoS protection by
       <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
        Cloudflare
       </a>
...
```

So, to avoid getting blocked with Selenium,   you have two options:

1. Don't run chrome in `--headless` mode
2. Add the `user-agent` header when in `--headless` mode

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
u = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'
driver.get(u)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.flexposts__item.flexposts__story')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select('.flexposts__item.flexposts__story'))

driver.quit()
```

Using the `requests` library is not possible.

**Further reading**:

- [Python - Request being blocked by Cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087990/python-request-being-blocked-by-cloudflare)
- [Denial-of-service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

u = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u, timeout=30, headers=headers)     # print(r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

soup.select('.flexposts__item.flexposts__story') # return []

print(r.status_code) #returns 200
```

Comment: It returns 200 when I execute it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to scrape the headlines with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# enter the location for chromedriver executable file
chromePath = "chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)

driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'
driver.get(url)

headlines = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('flexposts__story-title')

for headline in headlines:
    print(headline.text)
    print('')

driver.quit()
```

**Edit :**
For some reason, clicking on the "More" button doesn't work in the driver window.