# Python SSL Context with wrapped Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a `websocket` server that protected with `CloudFlare` through `upgrade: websocket` header. Expected result is `101 Switching Protocol`. Using a raw `Socket`, I was able to connect into the server but with several issues such as `SSLv3 Handshake Failure` or the server doesn't give any response; sometimes occur.

```
import ssl
import socket

socketch = ssl._create_unverified_context().wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname='unpkg.com')
socketch.connect(('unpkg.com', 443))
socketch.sendall(b'''GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: identity.o2.co.uk.zainvps.tk\r
User-Agent: cpprestsdk/2.9.0\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r
''')
print(socketch.recv(10000))
print('')
```

Using a raw socket is unstable, so I think it's better to use `requests` module.

```
import requests

heading = {'Host':'identity.o2.co.uk.zainvps.tk','Connection':'upgrade','Upgrade':'websocket','Sec-Websocket-Version':'13','Sec-Websocket-Key':'dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=='}

r = requests.get('https://unpkg.com', headers=heading)
print(r.status_code)
```

Using requests; the server responded with `403` status codes which means it's rejected by the `CloudFlare` protection but when using `Socket`, it gives the correct `101` status code. I'm assuming that it is because of wrapped socket gives an expected SSL Hostname through `server_hostname`.

Is this idea can also be implemented inside `requests.Session()`?

**UPDATE 1**:
Someone mentioning about the use of `CloudScraper` module to bypass the `CloudFlare` protection. Using `CloudScraper` still returns in `403` status code with Custom Headers.

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
url = 'https://unpkg.com'
sc = scraper.get(url, headers={"Host": "usaws1.sshstores.vip", "Connection": "upgrade", "Upgrade": "websocket","Sec-WebSocket-Key": "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==", "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13"})
print(sc.status_code)
```

[image]

Comment: Use CloudScraper, https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/ - it's really easy to setup and it works like a charm. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087990/python-request-being-blocked-by-cloudflare

Comment: I have used CloudScrapper but when using Custom Headers mentioned, it is also returns `403` status code. @user56700

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention you tried it, so I assumed you didn't.

Comment: I can see on the CloudScraper doc you can set a custom header, have you tried that?

Comment: Thread updated.. consider to checking it out :) @user56700